# Which channel processes are allowed in a $\phi^2$ theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Consider two real scalar fields $\phi$ and $\chi$, coupled by an interaction Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}_{int} = \lambda \chi \phi^2,$$

and consider the scattering process $ \phi +\phi \rightarrow \phi +\phi.$ I think that all of s-channel, u-channel, and t-channel (with an intermediate $\chi$ particle) will contribute to this, since each of these will have vertices with two $\phi$ particles and one $\chi$ particle. Is this right?

Also, won't these processes have various factors of 2 each from the equivalent contractions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, everything you wrote is correct - $\mathcal L_{\text{int}}$ allows for $s,t$ and $u$ channel contributions to the tree level scattering $\phi + \phi \rightarrow  \phi + \phi$ with $\chi$ as the mediator.

As written,  $\mathcal L_{\text{int}}$ is ignorant of the fact there are $2!$ permutations of the $\phi$ fields that can be contracted with the $\chi$ field in the context of the Wick expansion so a coupling constant $\mathrm{i}2\lambda$ should be attached to each of the vertices appearing in each of the three inequivalent diagrams mentioned above.

If one defines $\mathcal L_{\text{int}} = (\lambda/2!) \chi \phi^2$ with a compensatory factor of $1/2!$ then there is an explicit cancellation of numerical factors arising from the combinatorics and the coupling is then $\mathrm{i}\lambda$ in accordance with how we usually see standard $\phi^4$ theory with $\mathcal L_{\text{int}} \sim (\lambda/4!)\phi^4$ for which the coupling is $ \sim\mathrm i \lambda$.